# CSS3 Box-Shadow in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

i have a standard Android Webview in my application that open a page with some photos that have a box-shadow.

I don't know why there is the box-shadow under the Android Webview. In iOS and in normal Browser it works.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some code and UI

Comment: The code for the webview is the code for a standard webview... And the page is a standard html5 page width image in <div> and the box-shadow.

Sorry but i can't publish any link because it's for a work in progress product; i've no rights.

Comment: is there blue color box-shadow show ?